# Update partial columns in TDengine not working

Tags: tdengine

We use `insert into table1 (col1, col2) values(val1, val2)` to insert data into TDengine, at first it succeeds, but when inserting on the same record (exist timestamp), it just ignores the second insert data.

Reproduce:

```sql
create table tb1 (ts timestamp, value double);
insert into tb1 ('2022-02-02 08:00:00', NULL);
insert into tb1 ('2022-02-02 08:00:00', 2.0);
```

Is there a way to update a record paritally?

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter update that controls the logic of writing the same timestamp.
0：Not allow update
1：Whole line allow update
2：Some columns allow update